# Type in elastic search, that can be contains documents of different types

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to store some logs of different types in elasticsearch, each log has a date. Simplest way - store date in each types. But i guess, this decision can increase searching time. Is there exist possible to create date field, that can contain documents of different types?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just 'def' the function in another file and then recall it whenever it is needed by using strings and sub-routing.

I hope I was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a simple date translator which translates various date formats to one of ISO8601. ES will auto convert them to epoch milis.

You can verify if you various apps are giving dates in one of the accepted formats here.
http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html